# How to generate and resolve custom URLs with TYPO3 9.5

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Am using `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObj->typoLink` to generate a link and I have an additional parameter like this: `ext__pluginname[d64]=31511` and would like to return something like a/b/c. I would then want TYPO3 to give me back the link so I can resolve it when clicked. I've already tried `PersistedAliasMapper` but won't allow me to return anything with a slash in it. I've even tried a custom aspect mapper. I get the error:

```
Parameter "tx_ext__pluginname__d64" for route "enhancer_tx_ext__pluginname000000003e62d21a000000000514759a" must match "[^/]++" ("a/c" given) to generate a corresponding URL.
```

Am able to generate and resolve the slugs(urls). I can store them in db and retrieve them for that matter. No problem.

Am generating them from root page (uid 1).

How can i get this to work?

Comment: Have you added path segment field in you database and modal?

Comment: @gautamsinhmori Yes i have

Comment: Don't you think you will have to write YAML configuration for your custom extension? Take a look at the [EXT:News Docs](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/7.2/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html#common-routeenhancer-configurations) here. Here @Georg Ringer has created routing for his extension. Hope this could be helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have created the desired path in a database table or view already, making use of the [slug feature](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Slug.html) in the TYPO3 backend or creating it yourself.

You could then use the [PersistedAliasMapper](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html#persistedaliasmapper) in your site config (config/sites/default/config.yaml).

If you need multiple values in a single path divided by slashes (not a combined slug field), take a look at the [route configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/7.3/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html#human-readable-dates) for the news extension. You just have to use database mappers instead of static ones, but keep in mind this may impact the performance of the routing!

As you did not provide much detail about your use case, I don't really understand why you need such a path structure with slashes.

Comment: I've updated my question to make it more clearer. I've something like this: ext__pluginname[d64]=31511 and would like to return something like a/b/c and vise-versa. I've already tried PersistedAliasMapper but won't allow to return anything with a slash in it. I've even tried a custom aspect mapper. I don't know how else to do this.

Comment: You should not try to merge 3 different variables into one! You can provide `typoLink` method (and any other method to generate links) with multiple values a, b, and c instead of "a/b/c/" and provide a yaml config which handles URL generation and routing. Take a look at the archive urls of the news extension, there are variables like year and month, the separator is also a "/".

Comment: I can do that easily. But am generate variable-length urls. That is to say, the urls can be short like a/b/ or long like a/b/c/d/e/... depending on how deep the article is buried in the database. Each has different number of parents.

Comment: Ok, I see. Then my question is: why do you use a Content Management System to output the data in the first place? If your requirements are that special, then use a framework like Symfony or Laravel for this, as they are capable of this scenario. TYPO3 CMS is not a good companion if you already have datastructures outside the expected source and format of TYPO3. Is there any specific reason you prefer TYPO3 CMS over a web framework? (there also is "FLOW" if you like the TYPO3 universe)

Comment: I've worked with TYPO3 for years and can do alot with it. Am able to create URLs so am currently using urls like 'domain.com/12487' for output. With previous versions I had the ability to encode and decode my own URLs so easily. They took out the two hooks for doing that in the release of version 9. And to your point, actually to the contrary, TYPO3 is the most robust for this type of site. There's no need to overhaul and transfer everything to a new CMS just because of URLs. There are many more important aspects to it.